# How to handle undefined 404 from API Call for an image which is actually loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, es6-promise, rest

so basically the images are loading but i still get this error: **GET https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/undefined 404**

So how can I prevent that from happening? I tried onError, optional chaining and a condition. Those did not fix it. Could somebody explain me, why that is happening and how to fix it?

I am quite new in the field, I would really appreciate help.

My Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import clsx from "clsx";
import MovieCredits from "./MovieCredits.js";
import Trailer from "./Trailer.js";
import TransitionsModal from "./TransitionsModal.js";
import SimilarMovie from "./SimilarMovie.js";


export default function MovieDetails() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const params = useParams();
  const id = Number(params.id);
  const movieScorePercentage = movie?.vote_average * 10;

  const classNames = clsx({
    green: movieScorePercentage >= 70,
    yellow: movieScorePercentage < 70,
    red: movieScorePercentage < 40,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=${apiKey}&append_to_response=similar`
        );

        if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Problem getting movie details.");
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        setMovie(data);
      } catch (error) {
        // console.log(error);
      }
    })();
  }, [id]);

  const backgroundImage = {
    backgroundImage: `url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.backdrop_path})`,
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    objectFit: "cover",
  };

  function handleImageError(event) {
    console.log(event.target.src);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="header" style={backgroundImage}>
        <div className="poster">
          <img
            onError={handleImageError}
            src={
              movie.poster_path === null
                ? "https://res.cloudinary.com/dxdboxbyb/image/upload/v1620052094/ayi6tvyiedrlmjiim6yn.png"
                : `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/${movie.poster_path}`
            }
            alt={movie.title}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="details">
          <div className="title">
            <h1>{movie.title}</h1>
            <h1>({movie.release_date?.slice(0, 4)})</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="genres">
            <p>{movie.release_date}</p>
            <span>&#8226;</span>
            {movie.genres?.map((genre) => (
              <p key={genre.name}>{genre.name}</p>
            ))}
            <span>&#8226;</span>
            <p>{movie.runtime}min</p>
          </div>
          <div className="bookmark">
            <p className={classNames}>
              {movie.vote_average === 0 ? "NR" : `${movie.vote_average}`}
            </p>
            <span> User rating</span>
            <i className="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
            <i className="fas fa-star"></i>
            <button onClick={handleOpen}>
              <i className="fas fa-play"></i>Watch Trailer
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="plot">
            <h3>{movie.tagline}</h3>
            <h3>Plot</h3>
            <p>{movie.overview}</p>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span>Status</span> {movie.status}
            </li>
            <li>
              <span>Budget</span>{" "}
              {movie.budget === 0 ? "/" : `$${movie.budget}`}
            </li>
            <li>
              <span>Revenue</span>{" "}
              {movie.revenue === 0 ? "/" : `$${movie.revenue}`}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <MovieCredits id={id} />
      {movie.similar?.results?.length > 0 && (
        <h1 className="headline">Similar Movies you could like</h1>
      )}
      <div className="similar-movie-layout">
        {movie.similar?.results?.map((similarMovie) => (
          <SimilarMovie key={similarMovie.id} similarMovie={similarMovie} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <TransitionsModal open={open} handleClose={handleClose}>
        <div className="close-button" onClick={handleClose}>
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </div>
        <Trailer id={id} />
      </TransitionsModal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: at first render `movie.backdrop_path` is undefined because your fetch is not complete yet

Comment: @dbuchet that also applies for the second image?

Answer (score 1):

Well I fixed it like that. Probably not the best fix, but it kinda works.

```
  function backgroundImage() {
    if (movie.backdrop_path === null || movie.backdrop_path === undefined)
      return {
        backgroundImage: `url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dxdboxbyb/image/upload/v1620052094/ayi6tvyiedrlmjiim6yn.png)`,
        backgroundPosition: "center",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
      };

    return {
      backgroundImage: `url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.backdrop_path})`,
      backgroundPosition: "center",
      backgroundSize: "cover",
      backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    };
  }
```